# XMLDocument: Root element is missing

Tags: c#, xml

I'm working on a program to manage all customers we have in our company. I want to use an XML file to save the customers. So I create an XML file (if not existing) and fill it with elements. Here you can see how I do:

```
string path = "C:\\Users\\Römel\\Desktop\\Save";
List<Kunde> kunde = new List<Kunde>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xdocument = new XmlDocument();
    xdocument.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
    foreach (XmlNode xnode in xdocument.SelectNodes("Kundenverwaltung/Kunde"))
    {
        Kunde k = new Kunde();
        k.KundenNr = xnode.SelectSingleNode("KundenNr").InnerText;
        k.Nachname = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Nachname").InnerText;
        k.Vorname = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Vorname").InnerText;
        k.Adresse = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Adresse").InnerText;
        k.Ort = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Ort").InnerText;
        k.Telefon = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Telefon").InnerText;
        k.Mail = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Mail").InnerText;

        kunde.Add(k);
        listViewKunden.Items.Add(k.Nachname + " " + k.Vorname);
    }
}

private void btnAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\save.xml"))
    {
        XmlTextWriter xwriter = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\save.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        xwriter.WriteStartElement("Kundenverwaltung");
        xwriter.WriteEndElement();
        xwriter.Close();
    }

    Kunde k = new Kunde();
    k.KundenNr = txtKundenNr.Text;
    k.Nachname = txtKundeNachname.Text;
    k.Vorname = txtKundeVorname.Text;
    k.Adresse = txtKundeAdresse.Text;
    k.Ort = txtKundeOrt.Text;
    k.Telefon = txtKundeTel.Text;
    k.Mail = txtKundeMail.Text;

    kunde.Add(k);
    listViewKunden.Items.Add(k.Nachname + " " + k.Vorname);

    txtKundenNr.Text = "";
    txtKundeNachname.Text = "";
    txtKundeVorname.Text = "";
    txtKundeAdresse.Text = "";
    txtKundeOrt.Text = "";
    txtKundeTel.Text = "";
    txtKundeMail.Text = "";
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
    XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Kundenverwaltung");
    xnode.RemoveAll();

    foreach (Kunde k in kunde)
    {
        XmlNode xtop = xdoc.CreateElement("Kunde");
        XmlNode xkundennr = xdoc.CreateElement("KundenNr");
        XmlNode xnachname = xdoc.CreateElement("Nachname");
        XmlNode xvorname = xdoc.CreateElement("Vorname");
        XmlNode xadresse = xdoc.CreateElement("Adresse");
        XmlNode xort = xdoc.CreateElement("Ort");
        XmlNode xtel = xdoc.CreateElement("Telefon");
        XmlNode xmail = xdoc.CreateElement("Mail");

        xkundennr.InnerText = k.KundenNr;
        xnachname.InnerText = k.Vorname;
        xvorname.InnerText = k.Nachname;
        xadresse.InnerText = k.Adresse;
        xort.InnerText = k.Ort;
        xtel.InnerText = k.Telefon;
        xmail.InnerText = k.Mail;

        xtop.AppendChild(xkundennr);
        xtop.AppendChild(xnachname);
        xtop.AppendChild(xvorname);
        xtop.AppendChild(xadresse);
        xtop.AppendChild(xort);
        xtop.AppendChild(xtel);
        xtop.AppendChild(xmail);

        xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xtop);
    }

    xdoc.Save(path + "\\save.xml");

    e.Cancel = false;
    this.Close();
}
```

For `KundenNr`, `Nachname` etc. I created some classes in the end of my file. I hope it's not too much code.

First: I can't use the regular "X" button in upper right corner because there is no reaction if I hit it. So I created an `Exit` button.

Second: Everytime I hit the Exit button for leaving the program there comes an error at this line:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    xdoc.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
}
```

"The root element is missing" comes up. Does someone know this error and can give me a hint?

EDIT: For `btnExit_Click` I use this code:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you loading data when the form is closing?  Wouldn't you want to save it?

Comment: Yeah but I first have to load it. After that I'm saving it. See `.Save` at the end of `Form1_FormClosing` :) Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Ah, I was looking at your snippet that shows where the exception is rather than the full code.  What is in `save.xml` at the time you are loading?

Comment: Load up the xml with note pad, I suspect at some point the file has been stuffed up and you have no root node. Seeing as you are loading the file, wiping all the children and rewriting them, why not simply create a new one each time?

Comment: Mh, `save.xml` is empty

Comment: Odd that it wouldn't blow on form load, but an empty document means there's no root node (as the exception says).

Comment: Yeah that sounds logical. Is there a way to avoid this problem (with XMLTextWriter)? Because I don't want to create a root element for each .xml file

Comment: well there you go,you have some code for dealing with no file in addcustomerfile, use it n formclosing as well and delete the file. If I were you, I'd make this a bit more robust, like making sure the xml was valid, keeping a (valid!) backup of it and such. It's possible something might go wrong you see...

Comment: Why not? If you want a quick way. XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.LoadXml("<RootNode></RootNode>"); is all it is, and atleast you know it will be right.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson if I use `LoadXml("<RootNode></RootNode");` it doesn't know in which file. Or does it know?

Comment: And after put `LoadXml("<RootNode></RootNode")` instead of `.Load` method, there comes another error at `doc.Save();` methode: "an unhandled exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: XmlDocument has a save method, Hold on I'll post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Load `XmlDocument` from one thing and save it to another. It's an in memory representation. Given you are doing a total overwrite trying to deal with that is unnecessary, it's way more work than creating a root node.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
  xdoc.LoadXml("<Kundenverwaltung"></Kundenverwaltung>"); // You might want to put any xml directives, default attributes, etc. in here.
  XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("Kundenverwaltung");
  foreach (Kunde k in kunde)
  {
     //Create and add each Kunde node as before
  }
  xdoc.Save(path + "\\save.xml");
  e.Cancel = false;
}
```

So now all you do is delete the duff one you have now. 
I see some potential problems coming at you though.
The file is being written whether there are any changes or not.
`XmlDocument` holds all the content in memory, so this solution is only for smallish documents.
If as is the case here something (suspect a bug at some point), your file gets stuffed up, all the data is lost. You might want to consider something like the above, but save instead to a temporary document.
Then attempt to load or validate it, and if it comes back okay, then rename it to save, otherwise report the issue. That way at least only this "sessions" changes have been lost.

In general I never call XmlDoument.Load("Fred.xml") or save. I do something like.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using(FileStream rfs = new FileStream("OldFred.xml",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
   doc.Load(rfs);
   //do my reading stuff)
}
using(FileStream wfs = new FileStream("NewFred.xml",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
{
   //do my Writing stuff
   doc.Save(wfs);
}
```

The advantage of using FileStream is you'd get an immediate fail if Oldfred didn't exist, or you didn't have write access to the folder Where NewFred is for instance. It's a habit we picked up when dealing with concurrent and multi-user access to the file system. It means out XmlDocument reading and writing code never has to deal with the file system, the code that deals with the FileStreams takes care of that.

Comment: PS if you wanted to deal with big documents with XmlReader/ XmlWriter you would have two Files any way. Current and new, or old and current.

Comment: PPs If I was you I'd consider using FileStreams instead of LOad and save with a string, that way you'll know you file system problems instead of just passing strings to XmlDocument.Load and Save and crossing your fingers.

Comment: Okay, and is it a complete other way to go with `FileStream`?

Comment: I have to say you something: You are boss! Thank you very very much! It works PERFECTLY! One question: Are MAX. 200 customers too much for going with `XmlDocument`?

Comment: Shouldn't think so. Especially seeing as it's one hit to load and one to save. Just keep an eye on the size of the document. FileStream is just a little improvement. For instance unless you've blocked it, what would happen if you had two of your app running and they closed at the same time?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! You helped me a lot! I was trying so many ways like `XmlSerializer` or `Dataset` etc. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

XmlDocument is enforcing the rule that a valid XML document must have one root element.

Not sure exactly what your code is doing, but I suspect it is creating XML which might look like:

```
<Kunde ... />
<Kunde ... />
<Kunde ... />
<Kunde ... />
<Kunde ... />
```

... where it needs to look something like:

```
<Kunden>
    <Kunde ... />
    <Kunde ... />
    <Kunde ... />
    <Kunde ... />
    <Kunde ... />
</Kunden>
```

In other words, you need to create one and only one element to add directly to the document (which becomes your root element) and add all other elements inside that.

Comment: Hi. So everytime I create a new file with `File.Create` I have to edit the xml and add a root element manually? Is there no way to crate the root element promatically without any errors?

Comment: Of course you can do it programmatically. Just not sure the code you've written is doing what it needs to. Basically, when you create a new XmlDocument, you need to create an XmlElement which will be your "root", and add it to the XmlDocument. Then, as you create the XmlElements of your content, you add them to (or under) your "root" XmlElement, NOT directly to the XmlDocument itself. By the way... I started out using XmlDocument, but eventually switched to XDocument (Linq XML). If you're developing for .NET 4.0 or later, you should consider switching too - it's much easier to write.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm going to write another program for testing it and then I will use it :) Thank you