# Error login with XML

Tags: c#, authentication

im almost done with a big project and here's my last error. So I made a XML file where I can add some data, here's the code :

```
        string path = "XMLFile1.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("lmge;lm");
            XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
            XmlComment comment = doc.CreateComment("This is an XML Generated File");
            doc.AppendChild(declaration);
            doc.AppendChild(comment);
        }
        else
        {
            doc.Load(path); MessageBox.Show("Everyting is right?");
        }
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlElement Subroot = doc.CreateElement("Angajat");
        XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("Name");
        XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("ID");
        XmlElement password = doc.CreateElement("Password");
        XmlElement phone = doc.CreateElement("phone_nr");
        XmlElement address = doc.CreateElement("Address");

        nume.InnerText = textBox1.Text;
        id.InnerText = textBox2.Text;
        password.InnerText = textBox3.Text;
        phone.InnerText = textBox4.Text;
        address.InnerText = textBox5.Text;
        Subroot.AppendChild(name);
        Subroot.AppendChild(id);
        Subroot.AppendChild(password);
        Subroot.AppendChild(phone);
        Subroot.AppendChild(address);

        root.AppendChild(Subroot);
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        doc.Save(path);
        MessageBox.Show("Succes!");
```

And now I made a login where I get the error

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string filename = @"D:\Poriecte Visual\INFO2017\INFO2017\XMLFile1.xml";

        doc.Load(filename);

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("persoane"))
        {
            String Username = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;
            String Password = node.SelectSingleNode("Password").InnerText;

            if (Username == textBox3.Text && Password == textBox4.Text)
            {
                Form a = new Form4();
                a.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something is wrong");
            }
```

And I get this error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNYIT.png)

My XML file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Persoane>
 <Angajat>
  <Name>Horatiu Necula</Name>
  <ID>horatiu</ID>
  <Password>123</Password>
  <Phone_nr>0723626741</Phone_nr>
  <Address>Valenii de munte ,PH</Address>
 </Angajat>
</Persoane>
```

Help me, I've searched a lot the last few days but nothing worked :\

EDIT: someone helped me and it worked, the path was incorrect , but now I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line 70( string Username = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText; )

Comment: Is this actually what your XML file looks like? Why do you have whitespace in all your tags?

Comment: @Phylogenesis if I delete that whitespace the tags will disappear, in visual is without them

Comment: I have edited the question with valid XML.

Comment: I am not convinced, however. Your error message says that the root element is missing, which pretty much outright says your XML file is invalid in some way. Can you show the contents of the file?

Comment: here is my xml file [link](http://s10.postimg.org/dta75u7qx/2016_09_13_3.png) @Phylogenesis

Comment: That file appears to be in a different folder: `bin/Debug/XMLFile1.xml`.

Comment: it funny cuz I have one file in the main folder and one in bin/debug, thanks you for that, but now I get other error :) Here " string Username = node.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText;" I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." @Phylogenesis

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path to your xml file is correct?
This error may occur if the document at the path is actually empty.
Apart from that i would suggest loading the XML file with a FileStream as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061410/xmldocument-root-element-is-missing) as it gives you a more verbose error set if your file is not available or accesable.